# Retrieving data from combo box based table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database in MS Access with a table Main_Table where some fields are comboboxes, for example:

```
SELECT [Slave1_System].[ID], [Slave1_System].[System] FROM Slave1_System;)
```

I want to retrieve the value of the field "System" with id 2 and show it with MsgBox.

I have tried:

```
Set dbs = DAO.OpenDatabase("D:\test.mdb")
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE ID = 2")

MsgBox rs.Fields("System").Value
```

But it shows me ID of the row from Slave1_System table not the value that I want. How do I retrieve a value from combobox based field?

Comment: I suggest you read http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Answer (score 1):

Set the column width of the combo box columns before the one you want to show to 0.

Combo boxes display the value of the first non-0-width column corresponding to the table value.